# unable to redirect from modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, modal-dialog, simplemodal

Below is my code for a modal window/page. When I click the submit button, however, I want to navigate to the index.html page. I am however, not able to do that although I have made a form and set the action attribute to the page. I also tried navigating to some other links but it does not work.

I am using jquery.leanModal.min.js which I found online after some searching.

How can I navigate upon clicking the submit button?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  <title>Moi modal page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../css/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../js/jquery.leanModal.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="topbar"></div>
  <div id="w">
    <div id="content">
      <center><a href="#loginmodal" class="flatbtn" id="modaltrigger">Login to website</a></center>
    </div>
  </div>!
  <div id="loginmodal" style="display:none;">
    <h1>User Login</h1>
    <form id="loginform" name="loginform" method="post" action="index.html">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="txtfield" tabindex="1">

      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="txtfield" tabindex="2">

      <div class="center"><input type="submit" name="loginbtn" id="loginbtn" class="flatbtn-blu hidemodal" value="Log In" tabindex="3"></div>
    </form>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#loginform').submit(function(e){
    return false;
  });

  $('#modaltrigger').leanModal({ top: 110, overlay: 0.45, closeButton: ".hidemodal" });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove `$('#loginform').submit(function(e){return false;});`

Comment: @blex Thank you. So that line of code was basically allowing me not to submit to the next page?

Comment: Yes, returning `false` on an event prevents it from happening (can be used to disable links, or form submits). This is often useful for dynamic websites that load the links without reloading the whole page. This process uses Ajax (You can find more info on Google or on this site).